# How do I traverse an array to get the value of an object element, using a for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to traverse an array using a for loop, to get the elements of specific objects. I just want the elements of "title" and "Id."  However, I seem to be going wrong somewhere.

```
//My Array

 var newReleases=[
 {
  "id": 10774532
  "title":"Die Hard"
  "Genre": "thriller"
 },
 {
  "id": 10653296,
  "title":"Bad Boys", 
  "Genre": "thriller"
 }
 ]

 //My for loop

 function findId(title, id){
    for (var i=0; i < newReleases.length; i++){
        if (newReleases[i].id=== title || id){
            return newReleases[i]; 
        }
    }
    return null; 
}

console.log(findId(title, Id)
```

I want it to work similar to this forEach function:

```
videoAndTitlePairs = [];
newReleases.forEach(function (videos){
    videoAndTitlePairs.push({"id":videos.id, 'title':videos.title}); 
})

return videoAndTitlePairs;
```

Comment: `console.log(findId(title, Id)` -> are `title` and `Id` actually defined/initialised somewhere?  The code you've presented would error.

Comment: What @JamesThorpe said...it looks like you might be using name in one spot and title in another. There are other errors as well.

Comment: "_I want it to work similar to this forEach function_"  The `.forEach()` part and your `findTitle()` do completely different things... O.o

Comment: @Andreas Noted. But I want the findTitle() to do what the forEach does. How would I do that?

Comment: The `.forEach()` is used to get a copy of `newReleases` where the film objects have their `Genre` property removed. Your `findId()` searches an film by `id` and `title` and returns the first matching object. How are they supposed to do the same? I don't get it... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See equivalent code to `forEach` loop below:

```
var newReleases=[
 {
  "id": 10774532,
  "title":"Die Hard",
  "Genre": "thriller"
 },
 {
  "id": 10653296,
  "title":"Bad Boys", 
  "Genre": "thriller"
 }
 ];

function findId(newReleases){
        var idAndTitlePairs = [];
        for (var i=0; i < newReleases.length; i++){
            idAndTitlePairs.push({"id":newReleases[i].id, 'title':newReleases[i].title}); 
        };
        return idAndTitlePairs; 
    }

console.log(findId(newReleases));
```

Also you could create equivalent code with using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
 with code below:

```
var idAndTitlePairs = newReleases.map(function(obj){
    return {'id': obj.id, 'title':obj.title}
});
console.log(idAndTitlePairs);
```

Answer (score 2):

Close, your `if` condition is a bit off - specifically the `||` part:

```
if (newReleases[i].id=== title || newReleases[i].id === id){
```

You need to recheck the entire condition - `if x == 3 || x == 4` - not `if x == 3 || 4`

Full code:

```
function findId(title, id){
    for (var i=0; i < newReleases.length; i++){
        if (newReleases[i].id=== title || newReleases[i].id === id) {
            return newReleases[i]; 
        }
    } 
    return null; 
}
```

And call it:

```
var movie = findId(10774532, 10774532);
```

Comment: I get an error that says `title is not defined` when I make you alterations. How would I do that in this case?

Comment: @an1waukoni -- Are you sure you've passed in a `title` param/

Comment: Most likely related to @JamesThorpe comment on the question, `title` is not defined when it's being called.

Comment: @tymeJV Where would I place this `title` parameter? Can you write out what the code, with the title parameter in it, would look like?

Comment: @an1waukoni -- Edited the answer to include the full code and how to call it.

Answer (score 0):

In the first object of the array, commas are missing to separate key value pairs as well as the if condition is incorrect and there's a parentheses missing at the end of console.log, check the below corrected code.

```
 //My Array

 var newReleases=[
 {
  "id": 10774532,
  "name":"Die Hard",
  "Genre": "thriller"
 },
 {
  "id": 10653296,
  "name":"Bad Boys", 
  "Genre": "thriller"
 }
 ]

 //My for loop

 function findId(title, id){
    for (var i=0; i < newReleases.length; i++){
        if (newReleases[i].id === title || newReleases[i].id == id){
            return newReleases[i]; 
        }
    }
    return null; 
}

console.log(findId(10774532,10774532))
```

Answer (score 0):

`newReleases[i].id=== title || id)` just checks that `id` is defined, which isnt what you want. Try `newReleases[i].id=== title || newReleases[i].id] === id)`